# Black screen between Splash Screen and First Screen (iOS)

Tags: ios, flutter

I have a problem with my flutter application. On iOS, everytime I launch it, I see a black screen for 1-2 seconds before my first screen can be loaded. The behaviour is like the one showed in this 
[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpB_AdekLNc&feature=youtu.be)

I have setup a splashscreen editing LaunchScreen.storyboard.
This happens even if I try to launch the default flutter app (counter), and both in emulator and real device.

How could I solve this, or at least change it from a black screen to a white screen?

Comment: Set the window background color to white?

Comment: The background of the first page?

Comment: It's hard to tell without more details, but an issue like this should be reported to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues (there are many different "black screen" issues @ https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+%22black+screen%22)

Answer (score 2):

This answer is related to your question, I had the same problem as you and solved it with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74954824/16449728).

> I had a line like
> this in the `Info.plist` file in Runner:
>
> `<string>LaunchScreen.storyboard</string>`
>
> I changed this line like this:
>
> > `<string>LaunchScreen</string>`
>
> and the black screen went away.

by *muhammedhamza uysal*

Answer (score 0):

Usually this problem occurs due to use of *FutureBuilde* (for example use *FutureBuilde* to **Firebase.initializeApp()**).

In case you use it in Firebase plugins, initialize Firebase before **runApp** like this:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(); // << initialize before runApp
  runApp(MainApp());
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you see the black window background of the activity showing until Flutter renders its first frame you should add this on your AndroidManifest, between < activity> ... < /activity>

```xml
    <meta-data
       android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
       android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
```

Comment: someone asking on iOS side, but you give answer for android side