# Black screen on startup after updating flutter

Tags: flutter

I recently updated the flutter. For running flutter project I am using android via usb. And after updating every project on startup shows black screen. Previous version worked fine. I tried to change launch splash screen(`drawable/launch_background.xml`) in android to white but black screen shows after splash screen. 
This is the simple code I am trying to run

```
void main()=> runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
        home:MyHomePage(),      
    );
  }
}
```

So how can I remove black screen on startup?

The black screen like [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24688).
As I said black screen shows after updating flutter to a new version. And I downgraded the flutter version to old and black screen disappeared.

Comment: can you share the codeblock for MyHomePage

Comment: @Abhijith I just created a new flutter project in android studio and nothing has been changed.The codeblock is default

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same problem when I switched to beta channel of flutter.
I noticed there is another `launch_background.xml` file in `drawable-v21` folder.

[image]

so I copied the content of `launch_background.xml` in `drawable` folder to `launch_background.xml` in `drawable-v21` and it worked.

Answer (score 11):

I had a black screen after splash Screen on iOS. I had a line like this in the Info.plist file in Runner:

`<string>LaunchScreen.storyboard</string>`

I changed this line like this:

> `<string>LaunchScreen</string>`

and the black screen went away

Comment: It's working in FLUTTER: 3.10 

Comment: I searched a lot for the solution and found answers that were not related to the problem in iOS Native.
I even tried changing the LaunchScreen.storyboard and Main.storyboard files from Xcode to solve the problem but to no avail.

The solution in your comment solved my problem definitively.
Yes, the problem was actually in the Info.plist file.

Answer (score 4):

If you see the black window background of the activity showing until Flutter renders its first frame you should add this on your AndroidManifest, between < activity> ... < /activity>

```
<meta-data
       android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
   android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this problem is quite easy. I have been facing this problem since months and now I came up with a solution.

Run this command in terminal

```
flutter config --no-enable-android-embedding-v2
```

And from next project you won't face such problem. But make sure that 'enable-android-embedding-v2' is set to 'false' by running command

```
flutter config
```

on terminal.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my flutter project. It has a simple fix in the AndroidManifest.xml. Make sure that

```
       <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
        />
```

Is above

```
       <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
          android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
        />
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml