# flutter shows black screen at startup after localization

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-packages, flutter-android

My flutter app showing a black screen for a short period of time right after the splash screen on startup after I tried localizing the app. And I am not sure where the problem is. The problem is gone when I remove the localization. The app is not crashing and the problem occurs both on debug and release mode. I saw [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59372118/black-screen-on-startup-after-updating-flutter) and others related to the same subject but they did not work. Deleted the app from the phones (physical & emulator) then restart it but it did not work. I even created a new app and copied the Android folder over to the old project but the problem wasn't solved. I would appreciate very much if someone can help me fix it. I followed a tutorial on YouTube to do the localization. The example app also have the problem.

```
$ flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1379], locale 
    en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.6 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision 9b2d32b605 (5 weeks ago), 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -0800
    • Engine revision 2f0af37152
    • Dart version 2.10.5

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\masan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.53.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\masan\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.19.0

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tomson.book.deputy">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    
    <application
        android:label="Book App"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

app_localizations.dart

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class AppLocalizations {
  final Locale locale;
  Map<String, String> _localizedStrings;
  AppLocalizations(this.locale);

  static const LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> delegate =
      _AppLocalizationsDelegate();

  ///helper method to keep the code in the widgets concise
  /////localization are accessed using an InheritedWidget 'of'
  static AppLocalizations of(BuildContext context) {
    return Localizations.of<AppLocalizations>(context, AppLocalizations);
  }

  ///load the language json file from the lang folder
  Future<void> load() async {
    String jsonStr =
        await rootBundle.loadString('lib/lang/${locale.languageCode}.json');

    Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = json.decode(jsonStr);

    _localizedStrings = jsonMap.map((key, value) {
      return MapEntry(key, value.toString());
    });
  }

  ///called from every widget which needs a localized text
  String translate(String key) {
    return _localizedStrings[key];
  }
}

class _AppLocalizationsDelegate
    extends LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> {
  const _AppLocalizationsDelegate();

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) {
    return ['en', 'fr'].contains(locale.languageCode);
  }

  @override
  Future<AppLocalizations> load(Locale locale) async {
    AppLocalizations localizations = new AppLocalizations(locale);
    await localizations.load();
    return localizations;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReload(_AppLocalizationsDelegate old) => false;
}
```

main.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'connectivity_wrapper.dart';
import 'l10n/app_localizations.dart';
import 'services/app/app_properties.dart';
import 'services/app_theme/app_theme.dart';
import 'services/users/auth.dart';
import 'widgets/landing/get_started.dart';

//Entry point
void main() {
  Widget _defaultHome = GetStarted();

  runApp(
    MainApp(
      defaultHome: _defaultHome,
      root: buildAppRoot(_defaultHome),
    ),
  );
}

///build app root widget
Future<Widget> buildAppRoot(Widget defaultHome) async {

  ///app default theme
  var defaultTheme;

  ///reload theme from prefs
  Future<void> reloadThemeFromPrefs() {
    debugPrint("Pulling out theme id from prefs...");
  }

  await reloadThemeFromPrefs();

  return MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProxyProvider0<AppThemeService>(
        create: (_) => AppThemeService(defaultTheme),
        update: (_, prevThemeService) =>
            AppThemeService(prevThemeService.currentTheme),
      ),
    ],
    child: Consumer<AuthService>(
      builder: (cctx, auth, _) => MaterialApp(
        key: GlobalKey(),
        //list of all supported languages
        supportedLocales: [
          Locale('en', 'US'),
          Locale('fr', 'FR'),
        ],

        localizationsDelegates: [
          AppLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        ],

        localeResolutionCallback: (locales, supportedLocales) {
          for (var loc in supportedLocales) {
            if (loc.languageCode == locales.languageCode &&
                loc.countryCode == locales.countryCode) {
              return loc;
            }
          }
          return supportedLocales.first;
        },
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: AppProperties.appName,
        home: ConnectivityWrapper(
          child: defaultHome,
        ),
        theme: cctx.watch<AppThemeService>().currentTheme,
        routes: {},
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget defaultHome;
  final Future<Widget> root;

  const MainApp({
    this.defaultHome,
    this.root,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Widget>(
      future: root,
      builder: (_, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("${snapshot.error}");
        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return snapshot.data;
        } else
          return Container(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(
              0,
              105,
              170,
              1,
            ),
          );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Here is the issue]

Comment: Are you getting errors in log at app start?

Comment: There is no error or unusual warnings. The app works apparently as it should. To me the black screen is a sign that there is something not ok in the app. So I am trying to fix it. Thank you

Comment: Where are you declaring your localizations?

Comment: The localization delegate is in lib>I18n and the languages json files are in lib>lang. Thanks

Comment: Are you declared localization classes in app class (main class of the app)?

Comment: I updated the post. Thank you

Comment: Can you run your app in debug mode an handle and check all exceptions in runtime? For example, Android Studio automatically catches exception when you debug your app and showing breakpoint.

Comment: There are no error or warnings in the console. Everything work as they should except the black screen that shows between splash screen and first rendered widget.

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same problem situation as you and I have some observation below for your refrence.
I guess you apply the [flutter_intl](https://localizely.com/flutter-localization-workflow?utm_medium=ide_plugin&utm_source=androidstudio_readmore) to enable the app internationalize, due to there is a asynchronous future call inside the generated S.load method could be the root cause of the problem situation. You may also check another internationalize guidance on official [flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization), which apply SynchronousFuture implementation inside the very similar generated _AppLocalizationsDelegate.load method to avoid the problem.

Comment: my observation on github [here](https://github.com/Racinggavin/black_screen_inv)

Comment: I just resolve it with the latest commit on my github repro

Comment: Thanks! Using a `SynchronousFuture` in the `load` method solved my issue.

Comment: could you provide more info?SynchronousFuture in the load