# Flutter app show grey screen in release mode but works fine in debug mode

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying out flutter and currently following this tutorial 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6c_vHdbUfg

I notice that the app works fine in debug mode but when I try the apk on my phone the app shows a grey screen after the loading screen. I am not too familiar building apps on mobile and not sure what is causing the issue here. I've tried building the apk using the github project from the tutorial but it also have this issue. https://github.com/iamshaunjp/flutter-beginners-tutorial/tree/lesson-35

Comment: Can you please provide the code of the page that shows the grey screen?

Comment: @PedroMassango https://pastebin.com/773Jm3m6

Comment: try run these in terminal:
`flutter channel master`
`flutter upgrade`

Comment: I copied that tutorial project and didn't reproduce any "grey screen" on a Pixel 2XL. Maybe there's something unique with your phone or the flutter version you are using. What's your phone? and `flutter doctor -v`? Otherwise, maybe similar to "black screen" issues? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53641660/black-screen-between-splash-screen-and-first-screen-ios

Comment: Answer given in below link is working 100%. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60292922/pageview-display-grey-screen-when-in-release-mode/60293217#60293217

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60292922/pageview-display-grey-screen-when-in-release-mode

Answer (score 3):

## **It's a Flutter crash.**

I had the same issue and solved it by installing SENTRY error logging in my flutter project. 
It takes me for 30 minutes for installing and fixing :)

Here is a link to flutter official documentation about SENTRY:
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/maintenance/error-reporting

P.S. 
Also watch carefully for imports while installing, because you can have dart:html error.
see:
[Flutter build cannot find 'dart:html'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61484592/flutter-build-cannot-find-darthtml)

P.P.S 
Make sure you app have access to the internet in `AndroidManifest.xml` if you installing SENTRY

```xml
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this error and solved it.

If you are using window, on flutter console run all commands

```
flutter channel master
flutter doctor
flutter channel dev
flutter doctor
flutter channel
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Press y too accept all licenses

Then restart your PC

Comment: Can you offer an explanation of _why_ these commands address the problem? That will help developers who are new to Flutter figure out how to solve these types of problems on their own in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Catcher seems like a nice solution. I am having a similar issue and giving it a go
https://pub.dev/packages/catcher

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in code.

In your reference code Home.dart file you are setting up image and colour based on  condition (ternary operator)

```
String bgImage = data['isDaytime'] ? 'day.png' : 'night.png'; 
Color bgColor = data['isDaytime'] ? Colors.blue : Colors.indigo[700];
```

> error is : boolean expression must not be null

Because data['isDaytime] is null initially.

You have to set a option value if **data['isDaytime']** is **null**, like this

```
String bgImage = data['isDaytime'] ?? false ? 'day.png' : 'night.png'; 
Color bgColor = data['isDaytime'] ?? false ? Colors.blue : Colors.indigo[700];
```

Answer (score -3):

I had exactly the same problem and got it working.

What you need to do is add the following line in **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

this can be found at: **android/app/src/main/**

The reason as you can probably see is that android requires this permission to access http requests.