# Pageview display grey screen when in release mode

Tags: flutter

He everyone,

I have an issue with the following code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: PageView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

When I run it using "flutter run" it displays exactly what I need but when I use the "--release" parameter it completely stops working and displays a grey screen. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You're using **`Expanded`** inside a **Widget** **(Stack)** who has its own fit. In order to fix it, remove **`Expanded`** and apply the fit parameter to your **`Stack`**

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<ThisApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand, // StackFit.expand fixes the issue
      children: <Widget>[
        PageView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.yellow,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Using debug mode, you'd notice the stack trace telling your about that error. Because `--release` always try to avoid issues/crashes, will disable that part of the UI, aka = grey screen.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!!

Comment: you are awesome

Comment: I had the problem of the grey screen on a Huawei phone (Android 10), but not on my tablet (Android 5), or my Samsung note 9 (Android 10), or even on the emulator. All I did was remove the Expanded and it all worked again. Thank you.

Comment: Bruh, you saved me, i should have focused on stack trace.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, there were no errors or warnings in debug mode.
I fixed the **grey screen** by running the app in the `release mode`.

Using Android Studio,

- Connect a physical device
- Click on **Run** > **Flutter Run 'main.dart' in Release Mode**

[Running flutter app in release mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU3BF.png)

It will also save the apk at **`Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk`**

Comment: Also, in Run->Edit Configurations, add Build Flavor name

Answer (score 3):

The grey screen shows up in release instead of the red error message that shows up in debug builds because Flutter decided it was better than showing an error message to the user. In my case, one of my users was reporting the issue and I could not reproduce it. Turns out, if you have Crashlytics enabled, the errors show up as non fatals. This made it simple to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have used de debug to discover what was wrong and it was pretty verbose and precise on the position of the error (in my case it was the Positioned inside a Center widget).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because I have placed **Positioned** widget inside **Column** widget while it should be inside **Stack** widget.
I have only replaced **Positioned** with **Container** and removed the attributes (right, left, top) and the app worked perfectly in iOS release mode.