# Why release Apk display grey screen in android phone?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

When I use `Flutter run` my app work perfectly but when I get APK with `flutter build apk --release` command my app install perfectly but display a grey screen, and I added internet permission to main/manifest but still show grey screen:

flutter run --verbose output:

```
E:\Project\Flutter\Sobhan\NewRepositoryLast\mobile-app\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31:50 Warning:
[   +3 ms]      activity#com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity@android:launchMode was tagged at
AndroidManifest.xml:24 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
[   +6 ms] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[   +4 ms] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[        ] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[        ] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[        ] WARNING: Compatible side by side NDK version was not found. Default is 21.0.6113669.
[        ] Compatible side by side NDK version was not found. Default is 21.0.6113669.
[+3299 ms] Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libflutter.so.
[  +99 ms] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
[   +1 ms] Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
[        ] See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[        ] BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3m 4s
[        ] 354 actionable tasks: 314 executed, 40 up-to-date
[ +424 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 186.1s, longer than expected)
[ +128 ms] calculateSha: LocalDirectory:
'E:\Project\Flutter\Sobhan\NewRepositoryLast\mobile-app\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk'/app.apk
E: queries (line=25)
E: intent (line=26)
E: action (line=27)
[  +15 ms] I/flutter (16716): null
[ +242 ms] W/ConnectionTracker(16716): Exception thrown while unbinding
[   +3 ms] W/ConnectionTracker(16716): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lq@bcff89e
[  +11 ms] W/ConnectionTracker(16716):  at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1490)
[  +10 ms] W/ConnectionTracker(16716):  at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1655)
[   +1 ms] W/ConnectionTracker(16716):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:716)
[   +6 ms] W/ConnectionTracker(16716):  at
```

flutter doctor -v output:

```
E:\Project\Flutter\Sobhan\NewRepositoryLast\mobile-app>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.3 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 8874f21e79 (3 weeks ago), 2020-10-29 14:14:35 -0700
    • Engine revision a1440ca392
    • Dart version 2.10.3

 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Mahdi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\Mahdi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin installed
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.51.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Mahdi\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.16.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM G930F (mobile) • 988678384432514e4c • android-arm64 • Android 8.0.0 (API 26)

• No issues found!
```

And my phone is a Galaxy S7 with Android OS

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant, but have a look at - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60293217/5550161

Comment: I checked this before

Comment: Most of the time the error like this on design part,which screen shows grey screen,if it is just in a screen it might be design issue,run the project then look for `Incorrect use of Parent widget` warning this works with debug without any problem but in release build it shows blank screen or grey screen@abbas jafari