# My Flutter app works fine when running through Xcode on a real device, but the UI is broken on Testflight. Why?

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, user-interface, testflight

### Introduction

I'm working on a Flutter app for my company. Running it via VSCode, or even straight off of Xcode, on a connected, physical iPad works perfectly fine. Everything renders and plays exactly as it should without issue.

I go ahead and push the app up via Transporter so I can get it on Testflight. It uploads and appears in Testflight as a new build, no problems. I go download it on the same, physical iPad and start using it.

### The problem

The UI on the screen that follows Login is completely messed up. The two big important buttons that should be appearing are instead replaced by a gigantic grey box. Again, this is the exact same physical device, running what is, nominally, the exact same software. Anyone got any pointers here?

### Screenshots

Here's a picture of how the screen is supposed to look.

[image: The app running correctly, via Xcode on a connected iPad.]

And here's a picture of the app running via an install from Testflight on the same iPad.

[image: The app running with a broken UI via Testflight on the same iPad.]

Note that the white boxes in the top bar are just redacted personal data regarding the app and company intellectual property. The issue is within the large content panel.

Honestly, we're really not sure what to try. The app works when run via Xcode or VSCode. We've tried rebuilding it, deleting it, restarting the iPad in case there's caching issues, every time the same thing happens. We've spun new builds, and of course we're always hoping for the regular UI to appear, but the version from Testflight always breaks in the same manner as pictured above.

Comment: there are different possible solutions as mentioned in various stackoverflow post. In your case I would try running it in release mode and checking for logs. E.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60292922/pageview-display-grey-screen-when-in-release-mode

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me due to the incorrect use of `Expanded` widget or when `!` was used on a null variable.

In case of the Expanded widget, there will be an error in the console
`Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.`
If this is the problem then you should check where you are using the Expanded widget.

`Expanded widget must be used within a Column, Row, or Flex`.