# i get a grey screen when i click on this button

Tags: flutter, build

when i click on it in the simulator it works fine but after building the app and release it and install it on the phone it shows me a grey screen
[![enter image description here][image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCxoM.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCxoM.png)

Comment: Please confirm that the name argument of the screen you're navigating to is correct

Comment: it is correct it works in the simulator but after building the app and install in on a real android phone it shows a grey screen

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59502053/flutter-app-show-grey-screen-in-release-mode-but-works-fine-in-debug-mode?rq=1
Is this helpful for you?